# How print utf8 characters in array in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, arrays, encoding, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with print array with unicode

sample_data.csv:

```
Петр
Андрей
```

Here is the code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('sample_data.csv', delimiter=";")
print data
>>> ['\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x80', '\xd0\x90\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9']
```

But print only string show me this.

```
print data[0]
>>> Петр
```

How I can print array with correct strings?

Comment: Why do you need lists to print that way? Python is trying to protect you from unknown encoded data messing up your terminal by giving you *debugging* output; anything non-printable, non-ASCII data is shown as escape codes instead.

Comment: Just in debug cases